# Access-Control-Allow-Origin on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, header

how can i solve Access-Control-Allow-Origin problem on Codeigniter? I've tried header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); etc. But no response still have the problem. Need help about this one. Regards.

My PHP codes: http://codepaste.net/r27eua
My JS codes: http://codepaste.net/ev35me

Comment: This helps I think: http://competa.com/blog/2015/03/enable-cors-origin-resource-sharing-on-codeigniter-rest-server/

Comment: i tried but nothing happened :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where do you write the header code? I thing you have to write it on page which will be opened by your request!

Comment: after php tags top of class

Comment: in *js* line `url: web_url + "cart/fetch_cart"`, have try to put relative path like `url: "../cart/fetch_cart"` and see what happen ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question, but for sake of people who will bump in here like I did, this is how I solved my CORS puzzle.
If you use apache, make sure you have `mod_headers` enabled, this is enabled by default, but just to be sure, you can run `sudo a2enmod headers` in terminal.
Then on your .htaccess file, add the below code.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
</IfModule>
```

Voila...